# Get Emf image size ratio (Win32, C/C++)

Tags: c++, winapi

i want to convert .emf vector image file to .bmp using the win32 api and C/C++.

It works with a square image. But I do not know how to get the ratio of the size of the .emf image when it is rectangular.

The ENHMETAHEADER structure filled with the GetEnhMetaFileHeader () function does not seem to contain the correct information.
rclBounds and rclFrame of the ENHMETAHEADER structure give equivalent widths and heights while my .emf image is clearly rectangular (the height should be almost twice the width with my test image).

How can I get this ratio? how software like irfanview managed to do it?

Here is the code i use to get the image width et height:

```
BOOL CConvertEMFToBMP::ConvertToBMP(const char* strFileName, const char* strBMPFile, int w, int h, int div, int indexX, int indexY)
{
    HENHMETAFILE    hemf;
    HBITMAP         bitmap;
    HDC             memDC;
    ENHMETAHEADER   emh;

    HDC dc = ::GetDC(NULL);

    hemf = ::GetEnhMetaFileA(strFileName);

    ZeroMemory(&emh, sizeof(ENHMETAHEADER));
    emh.nSize = sizeof(ENHMETAHEADER);
    if (GetEnhMetaFileHeader(hemf, sizeof(ENHMETAHEADER), &emh) == 0)
    {
        DeleteEnhMetaFile(hemf);
        printf("Error: Can't get EnhMetaFileHeader\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    long frameWidth  = emh.rclFrame.right  - emh.rclFrame.left;
    long frameHeight = emh.rclFrame.bottom - emh.rclFrame.top;

    RECT rect;
    long width = emh.rclBounds.right - emh.rclBounds.left;
    long height = emh.rclBounds.bottom - emh.rclBounds.top;

...
}
```

With my .emf image:
Under IrfanView:
Original Size: 38208 x 52340  Pixels (1999.81 MPixels) (1.37)
Current Size : 19104 x 26170  Pixels (499.95 MPixels) (1.37)

Using my code:
width  = 165091
height = 165069

But for some image, it works...
Exemple with another image:

Under IrfanView:
Original Size: 9921 x 14030  Pixels (139.19 MPixels) (1.41)
Current Size : 9921 x 14030  Pixels (139.19 MPixels) (1.41)

Using my code:
width  = 9920
height = 14030

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're willing to help you. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55000186/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: Can you show what you have attempted? Post Your code along with your question

Comment: i have edited my question to add the code i use to get the width and height of the image

Comment: The code reads the header from the file itself, which per-spec is supposed to contain the bounding box of the image. If it doesn't then the file is technically 'wrong', but that's just quibbling. irfanview probably ignores those values, internally renders the image and calculates the bounding box itself, but that's only a guess as to it's behaviour. If you dump out the first ~40 bytes of the .emf file, you can determine the size it's specifying by reading the frame bytes (offset 24 bytes in 4x4byte items of the bounding frame)

Comment: IrfanView does not report correct dimensions of metafiles.  Not even close.